# Git - Mark file as new instead of moved/copied

Tags: git

Is there any way to force git to consider a file as new instead of moved/copied?

Use case:

1. I have a large file, `index.js`
2. I'm factoring out a small class from that file into `Helper.js` (only 10% of the `index.js`) and renaming `index.js` to `MyLib.js`. `MyLib.js` will have some minor changes related to importing symbols from `Helper.js`.
3. I need to recreate `index.js` as a new, 2-line file, that only re-exports symbols from `Helper.js` and `MyLib.js`.

I want the commit history to record renaming `index.js` to `MyLib.js` and treat the 2-line `index.js` as new, but git instead treats `MyLib.js` as completely new, and `index.js` as having lost 99% of its contents, down to only those 2 lines.

Comment: So you *want* to lose all of the history related to that file? If you change the contents enough in the same commit as moving, it (probably) won't be able to track it as a move.

Comment: @crashmstr basically I've moved a file, renamed it and change it content a lot and what I want is it to be tracked as a new file but it is being tracked as a move... what kind of makes sense but in this case I want to force the file as new. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: `git config diff.renames false`

Comment: @user4003407: that did not work for the scenario I've added to the question. The result was exactly what I described (`MyLib.js` treated as entirely new, and `index.js` lost all but 2 lines).

Comment: Why has a bounty been put on this? Only to accept an answer? There is no way to "mark" any files as new, moved, renamed. Git figures that out when showing diffs and status, it isn't stored. The best option is to pick one of the existing answers here because there is actually no way to do what is requested.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is : no, `git` does not allow you to store information about how files were moved.

`git` tracks *content*, not *diffs*.

When `git` displays the information :

```
$ git diff --name-status HEAD^ HEAD
M    fileA          # fileA has been modified
R    oldB -> fileB  # fileB has been renamed
A    fileC          # fileC has been created
```

it actually has *computed this information* by comparing the contents of the two commits. It has not stored the information : "actually fileC was copied from fileA, and fileA was re-created as a new file".

If two files have the same name in both commit, `git diff` will always compute "this file has been modified".

---

Option 1 : keep the history you have, and live with it.

Option 2 : you could try to do it in two commits

- create a first commit, where the only action is renaming file `index.js` to `MyLib.js`,

  - if you need the code to "work" -- for example so that unit tests or integration tests can be run on this commit -- update other modules so that they import `MyLib.js` instead of `index.js`
- create a second commit, where you apply the modifications you actually want to see

  - extract a small class from `MyLib.js` to `Helper.js`,
  - create a new `index.js` file with two lines and exported symbols,
  - if you had modified the imports in the first commit, modify them again in this second commit.

---

With option 2, some `git` commands (`git rebase`, or `git log --follow` for example) would detect the renaming step in the repo's history, because they always inspect the history one commit at a time.

Some other commands, that do not look at a commit per commit diff but at a "global" diff, would still behave as option 1.

For example : if you open a Merge Request (think `github`, `gitlab`, `Azure Devops` ...), the Merge Request interface  would still present you with :

- file `index.js` has been modified,
- file `MyLib.js` is an entirely new file

Answer (score -1):

Git is pretty smart figuring out when a file has been moved (if you delete the file and add it in the new location in the same commit, Git will figure out that the file has been moved).

If you actually want the file to be considered as "new" instead of "moved", probably the best option is to delete and add the file into its new location in separated commits.