# Disable rename detection during the Git commit to preserve history

Tags: git, rename, commit

I am new in Git and I am looking for a way to disable the automatic rename detection during operations like *add, rm, commit*.

It is mainly for reasons of clarity and maintenance of a computing code. Even if a new file B is quite similar to another existing Git file A at this moment, I would like to record B separately with no history coming from A.

With Git v2.31.1, it seems to work for *add/rm* operations thanks to the option "renames = 0".
The *.gitconfig* file :

```
[diff]
    tool = tkdiff
    renames = 0
[merge]
    renames = 0
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

Here is the situation I would like to avoid.

```
> cat FileA.txt 
This is a first line
Values are 2.D-4 1.D-1 5.D-3
This is the end

> git init
> git add FileA.txt
> git commit -m " Step 1 "

> cat FileB.txt
This is a first line
Values are 1.D-4 4.D-1 9.D-3
This is the end

> git add FileB.txt
> git rm FileA.txt
> git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    FileA.txt
    new file:   FileB.txt

> git commit -m " Step 2 "
 [master 4fe24cf]  Step 2
   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
   rename FileA.txt => FileB.txt (56%)

> git log --oneline FileB.txt
  4fe24cf (HEAD -> master)  Step 2

> git log --oneline --follow FileB.txt
  4fe24cf (HEAD -> master)  Step 2
  ccf5076  Step 1
```

I do not know if *git commit* relies on *git diff* to compute similarity indexes, but options used for *git diff*, like "renames = 0" or "find-renames=100", have no impact here. And I did not find relevant options to test in the Git documentation for the *commit* command.

How can I proceed ? are there any others options ?

Answer (score 4):

`git` does not store any information about how files were moved ; it tracks *content*, not *diffs*.

When `git` displays the information :

```
$ git diff --name-status HEAD^ HEAD
R    FileA.txt -> FileB.txt
```

it actually has *computed this information* by comparing the contents of the two commits. It has not stored the information : "actually, the user deleted FileA.txt, and FileB.txt was re-created as a new file".

---

As far as committing goes : there are no options there ; I don't think you can avoid the message printed by `git commit`.

Commands, like `git diff` or `git log`, which deal with inspecting and displaying diffs, have a [`--no-renames`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---no-renames) option :

```
# will not look for renames at all :
git diff --no-renames
```

You may be fooled by the syntax for [`-M | --find-renames`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Mltngt) :

> Without a `%` sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., `-M5` becomes `0.5`, and is thus the same as `-M50%`. Similarly, `-M05` is the same as `-M5%`. To limit detection to exact renames, use `-M100%`.

```
# So :
#  '100' will get translated to '.100' which is 10% ... :/
git diff -M100     # same as : git diff -M10%
#   add a '%' after the 100 :
git diff -M100%
```

---

*Extra notes :*

The difference between `--find-renames=100%` and `--no-renames` is :
if a file is *moved* (renamed without any modification)

- the former will display it as a Renamed file
- the latter will display it as one Added file/one Deleted file

If you use `git log --follow` : `--no-renames` is ignored, but renaming detection takes into account `-M`. For example : `-M100%` will only "follow" accross commits where that file was moved without modification.
Do note, once again, that `--follow` is *computed after the facts*, and is only a heuristic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was indeed wrong with the use of "find-rename". What is also a bit confusing is the result of *git status* just before the commit, because it do not correspond to what *git commit* will finally do or detect. On top of that, from a command like *git log --follow*, one can see sometimes that rename detection associates improbable files (an ASCII file to a binary one for example). So, if there is any way to prevent "Renamed files" in the repository (except for an explicit *git mv*), I am interested.

Comment: @Ernest : I think you understood the global points around renaming, I'll repeat in one sentence : git does not store in its commit any information about renaming ; "renaming" is computed from the diffs, by commands such as `git diff`, `git log`, `git show` ...

Comment: note that : `git mv [from] [to]` is a convenience shortcut to `mv [from] [to]; git rm --cached [from]; git add [to]` ; it doesn't *store* anything different in the commit information.

Comment: You may check other questions about renaming (or avoiding rename detections) with git. Here is an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700418/git-mark-file-as-new-instead-of-moved-copied/60927364

Comment: @Ernest: `git status` runs `git diff` internally (twice!) and by default uses `-M50%` for each diff. In earlier versions of Git there was no control option for this; modern Git has `git status --renames`, `git status --no-renames`, `git status --find-renames=<n>` and user configuration values. Meanwhile `git log --follow` automatically turns rename detection *on* (that's what `--follow` *means*).