# Preserve renames with git reset --mixed

Tags: git

When I use `git reset --mixed` on a branch where I used `git mv`, the renames are replaced by delete and recreate.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: renames are not really tracked by git so if it's detected as a deletion and an addition of a file with a different name, that's good.

Comment: you are describing the expected behvior of git, I tried to explain it in my answer. Can you give more details on your intentions ? for example: for what kind of task do you use `git reset` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **soft** instead of **mixed**.

```
git reset --soft <commit>
git commit -m "Preserve renames"
```

It moves the branch pointer to a specific commit without modifying the staging area or the working directory. This means that it keeps the changes you made, including renames, in the staging area.

Answer (score 0):

In git, there is no difference between "rename" and "deleted + added".

If you look more closely at what happened after your reset, you should see that `git status` mentions the deletion of a *tracked file* and the presence of an *untracked file*.

If you know of one individual rename and run :

```
git add <old_name> <new_name>
```

`git status` show now indicate that a *rename* is staged.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv says you can rename files. and git status indicates: "renamed:"

Comment: `git mv` combines *an actual rename of your file/directory on disk* together with actions in git index to track the renamed files instead of the original files. Inside git storage, there is no such thing as a renaming, it is the exact same thing as `git rm --cached old; git add new`

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231214/86072) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60927364/86072)